# How can I achieve a reversed transition when the FragmentManager's back stack is popped manually?

Tags: android, android-fragments, transition

I'm using the v4 compatibility library and switch to new fragments like this:

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
 transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragmentContainer, event.getFragmentClass().newInstance(), FRAGMENT_CONTENT);
 transaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTransactionName);
 transaction.commit();
```

Now, when I want to return to a previous fragment programmatically without polluting the user's back stack with new fragment transactions, I use `popBackStackImmediate()`:

```
 if (fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(fragmentTransactionName, 0)) {
     return;
 }
 // apparently popping back to that fragment was not successful,
 // make a regular transaction now
```

This works all fine as is, despite that the animations that have been used to animate to one of the popped fragments are not reversed. I also tried to use `transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)` beforehand, but this did not even show a transition when the regular transaction took place, neither does it show on reverse.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say I have to Read The Fine Manual (TM) better:

```
public abstract FragmentTransaction setCustomAnimations
                (int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit)
```

> "Set specific animation resources to run for the fragments that are entering and exiting in this transaction. The popEnter and popExit animations will be played for enter/exit operations specifically when popping the back stack."

([Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations))